# Custom sorting DataTables column by date part of the value

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, datatables

I use jQuery [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) in my code.
One of my columns has values,  like:

```
AB 05-05-2019
CD 01-05-2019
EF 09-05-2019
```

When I click this column's header, I want it to get sorted only by using date, not by the prefix ('AB', 'CD', 'EF'). The result should be like:

```
CD 01-05-2019
AB 05-05-2019
EF 09-05-2019
```

What I've tried is, inserting a hidden column only with the date and when I sort column with the prefix, I sort my hidden column using JavaScript.
But, is there any proper way by using default configuration of jQuery DataTables?

Comment: How is it going? Have you solved the issue or still looking for some better answer?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming, your values are dates in the format 'DD-MM-YYYY' prefixed by two characters and a space, you may built your own little sorting plug-in, with custom sorting function like that:

```
(first, second) => {
    const firstDate = new Date(first.substr(3).split('-').reverse().join('-'));
    const secondDate = new Date(second.substr(3).split('-').reverse().join('-'));
    return firstDate - secondDate;
};
```

So, your complete example might look something like this:

```js
//source data
const srcData = [{
  id: 1,
  value: 'AB 05-05-2019'
 }, {
  id: 2,
  value: 'CD 01-05-2019'
 }, {
  id: 3,
  value: 'EF 09-05-2019'
 }
];

//datatable initialization
const dataTable = $('#mytable').DataTable({
  dom: 't',
  data: srcData,
  columns: ['id', 'value'].map(header => ({
    title: header,
    data: header
   })),
  columnDefs: [{
    type: 'prefixedDate',
    targets: 1
   }
  ]
 });
//extract Date part of the string
const extractDate = str => new Date(str.substr(3).split('-').reverse().join('-'));

//custom sorting
Object.assign($.fn.DataTable.ext.oSort, {
  'prefixedDate-asc': (a, b) => extractDate(a) - extractDate(b),
  'prefixedDate-desc': (a, b) => extractDate(b) - extractDate(a),
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<table id="mytable"></table>
</body>
</html>
```